# findContours for blob finding

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV's `findContours()` for blob-finding, by floodfilling at an arbitrary seed point in the contour and taking the bounding rectangle of the floodfill.  However, when two blobs touch at a corner, e.g.

[image]

they share a contour, so only one of the two blobs will be floodfilled, depending on which seed point was chosen.

I could change the floodfill connectivity setting from 4 to 8, so that the blobs are fused in the floodfill.  What I'd really like to do instead is ignore the small defect and count only the big blob.  Can this be done without substantially changing the algorithm?

Comment: Just a note; you can extract bounding rectangle directly from contour, you don't have to fill the image first.

Comment: Yes, good point.  I floodfill onto a mask to remove noise inside the bounding rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike for floodfill, there's no way to use findContours with 4-connectivity natively in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `findContours()` [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours).

`findContours` can return multiple contours if they appear in the image, in your case, if you choose 4-connectivity, you should get 2 `contours`, and then you can compare their bounding box size to decide which one to keep.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread('test.png', 0);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for (size_t i = 0;i < contours.size(); ++i) {
   cv::Rect bbox = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
   std::cout<<"Contour"<<i<<" Area"<<bbox.area()<<std::endl;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's the way I call findContours, and it gives a single contour.  The documentation you linked to says nothing about 4-connectivity.  How do you get 2 contours from findContours?

Comment: You are right, didn't notice it doesn't provide the option. And after looking into the source code, found it's hard coded to 8 connectivity.

Comment: Oh well.  Yet another bad API choice from the OpenCV folks.